# analogue of the round() function for turning 0.5 into 0

Tags: kotlin, rounding

Hi I need in analogue of the round() function for turning 0.5 into 0.
for example 0.4 -> 0 ; 9.5 -> 9 ; 10.6 -> 11

Im try too make

```
     var height = Math.round(width / firstNum * thecondNum).toInt()
    var e = height.toDouble()
    var roundedHalfDown = e.toBigDecimal().setScale(0, ROUND_HALF_DOWN).toDouble().toInt()

  
    return ("$width x $roundedHalfDown").replace(" ","")
}
```

also I tryed this

```
 var height = Math.round(width / firstNum * thecondNum).toInt()
    var e = height.toDouble()
    var r = Math.floor(e)
    if ((height % 10) == 5){
        
      r -= 1
        return ("$width x $r").replace(" ","")
    }
    
    else return ("$width x $height").replace(" ","")
}
```

the test says
4:3, width = 1457 expected:<1457x109[2]> but was:<1457x109[3]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first suggestion via `setScale` works as expected for your given inputs, no need for the intermediate `toDouble()` on the output from `BigDecimal`:

```
fun Double.roundDown() = toBigDecimal().setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).toInt()
```

```
fun testOutput(input: Double) = 
  println("%.4f rounded to %d".format(input, input.roundDown()))

testOutput(0.4)    // 0.4000 rounded to 0
testOutput(9.4999) // 9.4999 rounded to 9
testOutput(9.5)    // 9.5000 rounded to 9
testOutput(9.5001) // 9.5001 rounded to 10
testOutput(10.6)   // 10.600 rounded to 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe just subtract the smallest possible interval from your values (depending on data type), so that 0.5 -> 0.49999999 and is then rounded down.